# Using an alias of command that includes awk

Tags: awk, alias

```
alias ip="ifconfig eth0 | grep '255$' | awk '{print '\$2'}'"
```

Using the command `alias` with no argument I then get

```
alias ip='ifconfig eth0 | grep '\' '255$'\'' | awk '\''{print '\''$2'\''}'\'''
```

However, if I run `ip`, I will get

```
inet xxx.xxx.x.xxx netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.x broadcast xxx.xxx.x.xxx
```

When I run `ifconfig eth0 | grep '255$' | awk '{print '\$2'}'`, I can get my IP only successfully like `xxx.xxx.x.xxx`.

I feel confused about this condition. Could you help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Past all that quoting hell, what you end up running is `awk '{print }'`. That's because in the alias assignment `\$2` is in a double-quoted string, where the backslash prevents expanding `$2`, but when the alias is used, the `$2` is left unquoted and expands to whatever the current positional parameter `$2` is, probably empty in your interactive shell. The `print` command without any arguments prints the whole input line.

It's easiest to see with `set -x`:

```
$ set -x
$ ip
+ grep '255$'
+ /sbin/ifconfig eth0
+ awk '{print }'
        inet ...  netmask 255.0.0.0  broadcast 10.255.255.255
```

<sub>(And I seem to have my netmask wrong on that interface.)</sub>

Things like this are easier done with a function, since then you don't need to quote the whole command:

```
myip() {
    ifconfig eth0 | grep '255$' | awk '{print $2}'
}
```

However, `awk` can do what grep does, and we probably shouldn't match on the `255` but perhaps the `inet` keyword, so:

```
myip() {
    ifconfig eth0 | awk '/inet/ {print $2}'
}
```

or still a bit more explicitly:

```
myip() {
    ifconfig eth0 | awk '$1 == "inet" {print $2}'
}
```

which also avoids `/inet/` matching could match the `inet6` line, too.

Note that `ip` is [another utility](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip.8.html).

Comment: Thanks a Ton . I am new about linux .I will try with a function to solve the problem.

Comment: I forgot to reply that the 255 in the '255$' has no unique meaning,the only reason of the number is that the ip address i wanted is ended with 255 while others are all not.

Comment: @Jacob, yeah, I thought so. But doesn't `ifconfig eth0` show only one IP? You could have multiple on the same interface, but doesn't it then create those `eth0:0` etc. pseudo-interfaces? Not sure if there was a way to have them show under the one interface.

Comment: @ikkachu,actually,there's only one IP when i did so.Maybe it's because the device is a Hyper-V Virtual Machine,And the ip is connected with my real computer(I use a Microsoft Netwprk Adapter Multiplexor Driver).When it comes to a real device,something may go wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I have just replicated it in my PC, can you please try

```
alias ip="ifconfig eth0 | grep '255$' | awk '{print \$2}'"
```

This worked for me.

Make sure to `source .bashrc` after updating

Comment: There is seldom a reason to filter the input to `awk` with `grep`.  Instead, just use `awk '/255$/ { print $2 }'` (then add extra quoting unless you put it in a shell function, which you probably should).  Also, this answer is correct, but does not explain what the issue is nor how the modified code solves it. Additionally, the name `ip` may clash with other utilities on some platforms.

Comment: Thanks a lot anyway,but I really want to know the reason of  the answer.Could you explain about that ?